# Declare value based on date range without year

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-access-2010, excel-2010

I have about 10000 records in an Excel sheet (although I can import into Access 2010 if easier) and I need to set a value in a separate column if the dates fall between certain planting seasons. Year is irrelevant.

Thus if a date falls between a certain range, the column is filled in with its appropriate planting season.

```
Spring = 3/16 - 5/15 
Summer 5/16-8/15 
Fall 8/15-10/31 
Everything else is Null

3/20/2015 and 4/16/2013 are both "Spring" in the seasons column
6/28/2011 and 8/1/2015 are both Summer, etc.
```

Ideas as to how I can do this? As I said I can do it in either Excel or Access, whichever approach is easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few of helper columns to extract month and date would be useful (Assume values are at A1:A1000):

> B1 = `MONTH(A1)`
>   C1 = `DAY(A1)`
>   D1 = `DATE(2000, B1, C1)`

We intentionally "cheat" about the year for easier comparison.
After that, there's nothing special to do here, just a lot of nested `if`s:

```
IF(AND(D1 >= DATE(2000, 3, 16), D1 <= DATE(2000, 5, 15)), "Spring",
   IF(AND(D1 >= DATE(2000, 5, 16), D1 <= DATE(2000, 8, 15)), "Summer",
   IF(AND(D1 >= DATE(2000, 8, 16), D1 <= DATE(2000, 10, 31)), "Fall", "Winter")))
```

Comment: The formula worked with one exception, B1=Month(A1). I am unsure why you wanted to advance a month.

Comment: @user12059 because my mind was in JavaScript :-). Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DateSerial Function](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/DateSerial-Function-A0128476-83A0-407C-831A-93F2B046F503) in an Access query.  For example your spring season for planting date could be expressed as ...

```sql
planting_date BETWEEN DateSerial(Year(planting_date), 3, 16) AND DateSerial(Year(planting_date), 5, 15)
```

You could use similar patterns in a [Switch](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Switch-Function-d750c10d-0c8e-444c-9e63-f47504f9e379) expression to determine the planting season for each `planting_date` ...

```sql
SELECT
    y.planting_date,
    Switch
        (
            y.planting_date BETWEEN DateSerial(Year(y.planting_date), 3, 16) AND DateSerial(Year(y.planting_date), 5, 15), 'spring',
            y.planting_date BETWEEN DateSerial(Year(y.planting_date), 5, 16) AND DateSerial(Year(y.planting_date), 8, 15), 'summer',
            y.planting_date BETWEEN DateSerial(Year(y.planting_date), 8, 16) AND DateSerial(Year(y.planting_date), 10, 31), 'fall',
            True, Null
        ) AS season
FROM YourTable AS y;
```

If you want to store those season values in a field named *planting_season*, use the `Switch` expression in an `UPDATE` query ...

```sql
UPDATE YourTable AS y
SET y.planting_season =
    Switch
        (
            y.planting_date BETWEEN DateSerial(Year(y.planting_date), 3, 16) AND DateSerial(Year(y.planting_date), 5, 15), 'spring',
            y.planting_date BETWEEN DateSerial(Year(y.planting_date), 5, 16) AND DateSerial(Year(y.planting_date), 8, 15), 'summer',
            y.planting_date BETWEEN DateSerial(Year(y.planting_date), 8, 16) AND DateSerial(Year(y.planting_date), 10, 31), 'fall',
            True, Null
        );
```

Comment: I already had the data in Excel and Amit's answer worked so I did not see a need to try your suggestion out. Maybe someday when I am not way behind schedule I can test it out.

Answer (score 1):

This formula assumes the first date is in cell A1. Enter the formula in cell B1 (or another empty cell from row 1):

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(A1-DATE(YEAR(A1),1,0),{0;75;136;227;305},1),"","Spring","Summer","Fall","")
```

Now copy downward as far as needed.

That's it.

Note: this works by calculating the day of the year, for example March 16 is the 75th day of the year. Once the 'day of the year' is calculated, a simple binary match is performed on an array of day numbers that correspond to your planting seasons. Finally, the CHOOSE function is used to translate the MATCH results to the name of the season.

To edit your planting schedule, simply adjust this 'days of the year' array: {0;75;136;227;305}

Note: this is an extremely efficient self contained formula. No external helper columns are required and there are no IF functions, nested or otherwise.

Addendum: here is a variation that has a clause that deals with Leap Year:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(A1-DATE(YEAR(A1),1,0),{0;75;136;227;305}+(2=MONTH(DATE(YEAR(A1),2,29))),1),"","Spring","Summer","Fall","")
```

Comment: @user12059 Please consider this direct approach. It is a simple lookup without the need for any helper cells and no nested IF functions.

Comment: I am not sure where you are declaring the date ranges. The beauty of Amit's answer is that is is easy to follow and I know how and where to edit the date ranges should they change. Perhaps a breakdown of what your formula does would help.

Comment: @user12059 The answer has been updated with an explanation of how it works. Please reconsider your answer selection. This answer uses four function calls and is many times more efficient than the selected answer... which uses fifteen function calls in addition to three helper columns.